# Repeat a string with spaces between copies

Tags: ruby, string-concatenation

This should be really simple. I want to repeat a string in Ruby this way:

```
def repeat(input, n)
   n.times input
end
```

The problem is, I need to add spaces between the `input`s, without adding a space after the last input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
def repeat(input, n)
  ([input] * n).join ' '
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple,

```
def repeat(input, n)
   ( "#{input} " * n ).strip
end
```

Comment: Nice! The strip method removes leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
def repeat(input, n)
  Array.new(n, input).join ' '
end
```